# C# Use async or thread for long running database activity in Azure SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, async-await, azure-sql-database

I have a nightly C# Windows service that updates tables and calls a long running (~ hour) stored procedure on 5-10 Azure SQL databases.  Since I can run all database work at the same time in Azure SQL with little to no performance hit, I'd like to run them asynchronously.  I can either call a method with async void (using Await Task.Delay(10)) or create a new thread.

What is the better approach?... does it matter?

EDIT: Here is an example of the asynch void method.  I want to make sure it's clear what it's doing.

```
 public static async void DoRanking(object e)
    {
        // will start all orgs concurrently
        await Task.Delay(10);
        ... do a bunch of database work here ...
        ... call a long running stored procedure here ...
    }
```

Comment: Wait, I think you misunderstood what `Task.Delay` accomplishes. It is basically a sleep function, so it doesn't make any of your Tasks asynchronous.

Comment: You can only do what you want if the database supports Locking.  If you have a database with 10 items and one task remove 8 items and the second removes 4 items what is the results?  Can you have -2 items in the database?

Comment: Arthur: while await might not have been designed for what I asked, it does work that way.  I don't care when the method finishes so I call it, it waits 10 millies, and returns while the rest of the task finishes on its own over the next hour.  jdweng: the database work is quite happy without locking.  The stored procedure (one task) is running in each database at the same time and it doesn't interfere with itself.

Comment: IMHO, Theoretically It would be better to use async tasks because your process is mainly io bound. But in practice It doesn't matter, because 5 to 10 threads don't hurt too much.

Comment: Why do you want to use `async void` _specifically_?

Comment: mjwillis: The main purpose it to start the database work on all databases at the same time.  Then go about some of the other nightly tasks that don't depend on that work.

Comment: I would focus on stored procedures, its correctness and efficiency, since they take one hour, instead of worrying about how to call them the best way. Just call them in parallel, and problem solved

Comment: Jesus: That's exactly what I'm trying to do... call them in parallel (or close to it) in a C# windows app.  To do that, I have to call each SP in its respective database (in a loop) and don't want to wait until one finishes before calling another.  The SP is very good, it just has a ton of data to process.

Comment: Wouldn't TPL be ideal in this case? Parallel.For / Parallel.Foreach are demo'd here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/samples/dotnet/samples/parallel-programming-compute-pi-cs/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the older Thread/ThreadPool APIs or the newer TPL.  But in either case you shouldn't just start a long-running process on a threadpool thread.

Use a new Thread or a LongRunning Task:

> Specifies that a task will be a long-running, coarse-grained operation
> involving fewer, larger components than fine-grained systems. It
> provides a hint to the TaskScheduler that oversubscription may be
> warranted. Oversubscription lets you create more threads than the
> available number of hardware threads. It also provides a hint to the
> task scheduler that an additional thread might be required for the
> task so that it does not block the forward progress of other threads
> or work items on the local thread-pool queue.

[Documentation for `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCreationOptions_LongRunning)

Comment: TPL is very interesting, hadn't looked at that before.  Parallel.Foreach might be great.  What is the advantage of TPL over using an async method?

Comment: TPL is the framework that makes the async language features work.  Async methods return Task objects, and `await` pauses your code's execution until the Task is complete.

Comment: David:  I'm using await a little diferently... I call the DoRanking method (see edit in original post), it waits for 10 millies, and returns to the main thread.   However, the work in the method continues until it completes an hour or so later.  It appears to accomplish the same thing as TPL only differently.  I was just wondering if I'm doing something bad.  ;-)

Comment: You should have that method return a Task, and then keep track of the task in the calling code.  What you have works, but it's "fire-and-forget" without any central coordination of the work.

Comment: David:  What would I do with the task?  There is no information returned from the SP.  All work in the method is in a Try/Catch and I email myself any errors as part of the standard practice in the app.  Fire-and-forget is pretty much what I want.  The "calling code" has long since finished and it doesn't want to wait around to find out what happened.  It the returned "Task" fires off a "completion method" that's disconnected from the calling code, that might be worth while.  Does it do something like that?

Comment: Yes. You can append a common "completion method" or "continuation" with `Task.ContinueWith` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-5.0